# Copying data from one sheet to another where headers match

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from a base sheet to another sheet where the headers match. I have everything defined an the code runs without any errors. But the issue arising is that it only copies the first line and not all the lines from the base sheet into the new sheet. This could be due to some issue in the for loops I have. The code I used is as below:

```
mHeaders = Array("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3")
soHeaders = Array("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3")

wsDestHeaders = getIndexes(wsDest.Rows(2), mHeaders) 'mheaders includes the headers of sheet 1
wsSrcHeaders = getIndexes(wsSrc.Rows(2), soHeaders) 'sheaders includes the headers of sheet 2

'Setting first and last row for the columns in both sheets
    wsDestSORow = 3              'The row we want to start processing first
    wsDestEndRow = wsDest.UsedRange.Rows(wsDest.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    wsSrcSORow = 3              'The row we want to start search first
    wsSrcEndRow = wsSrc.UsedRange.Rows(wsSrc.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

For i = wsDestSORow To wsDestEndRow        'first and last row
            For j = wsSrcSORow To wsSrcEndRow 'first and last row
                    'copying data where headers match
                    For k = LBound(wsSrcHeaders) To UBound(wsSrcHeaders)
                        wsDest.Cells(i, wsDestHeaders(k)) = wsSrc.Cells(j, wsSrcHeaders(k))
                    
                    Next k
                Exit For
            Next j
         Exit For
     Next i

Function getIndexes(toSearch As Range, aValues As Variant) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim var As Variant
Dim aRes As Variant
    'determining the size of the array of headers
    ReDim aRes(LBound(aValues) To UBound(aValues))
    For i = LBound(aValues) To UBound(aValues)
    'matching the array values to the headers in the header row
        var = Application.Match(aValues(i), toSearch, 0)
        'returns the column index  number
        If Not IsError(var) Then
            aRes(i) = var
        Else
            MsgBox "Column '" & aValues(i) & "' was not found in " & toSearch.Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
            End
        End If
    Next i
    getIndexes = aRes
End Function
```

I have been trying everything I know but still didn't get the required output. Any help for the same will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you fill `wsSrcHeaders` array? Does it contain the columns number, the columns address or something else. I would suggest to edit the question and include this part of your code, It may be relevant... Then, I would also suggest to use an array of matching headers and copy all columns in discussion at once.

Comment: Hi, I included the part you asked for in the code. I'm not sure how to do the second part you mentioned

Comment: I was referring at `wsSrcHeaders` you are using in the code. Where in your code do you use the two added arrays? And, why being two arrays and not only one keeping the columns which must match?

Comment: In which row of each sheet do the headers exist?

Comment: The headers are in row 2

Comment: I have also added the portion you asked for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not answer my clarification questions...

Please, test the above code. It assumes that the headers row is the second one in both involved sheets. Please set the source and destination sheets in a way to match your existing ones:

```
Sub testCopyColunsByHeaders()
  Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsSrcEndRow As Long
  Dim arr, wsSrcHeaders, El, matchS As Long, matchD As Long, rngHS As Range
  Dim lastColS As Long, lastColD As Long, headersRow As Long, rngHD As Range
  
  headersRow = 1          'use here the row where the headers exist
  wsSrcHeaders = Split("Column 1,Column 3,Column 9", ",")
  Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet 'use here your source sheet
  Set wsDest = wsSrc.Next 'use here your destination sheet

  wsSrcEndRow = wsSrc.UsedRange.rows.count  'last row of the source sheet
  lastColS = wsSrc.UsedRange.Columns.count  'last col of the source sheet
  lastColD = wsDest.UsedRange.Columns.count 'last col of the destination sheet
  Set rngHS = wsSrc.Range("A" & headersRow, wsSrc.cells(headersRow, lastColS))   'headers range
  Set rngHD = wsDest.Range("A" & headersRow, wsDest.cells(headersRow, lastColD)) 'headers range
  
  For Each El In wsSrcHeaders 'iteration between headers array elements
    matchS = IsMatch(rngHS, CStr(El)): matchD = IsMatch(rngHD, CStr(El)) 'extract the matching pos
    If matchS > 0 And matchD > 0 Then
        'build the array to be transferred:
        arr = wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.cells(3, matchS), wsSrc.cells(wsSrcEndRow, matchS)).Value
        wsDest.cells(3, matchD).Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr 'drop the array at once
    Else
        'warning in case of not matching header:
        MsgBox El & " header does not exist in both sheets..."
    End If
  Next
End Sub
Private Function IsMatch(rng As Range, strS As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    IsMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(strS, rng, 0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        IsMatch = 0
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Please, test it and send some feedback or clarification questions if something not clear enough.

Declaring all involved variables will help you keeping a tidy piece of code and easily debug it in case of problems...

If you want copying the first three columns, no need of any iteration. All of them cam be copied at once.

Comment: Wow, this code worked perfectly! Got the exact output I was looking for!

Comment: Could you please explain what matchS and matchD is doing? What did you mean extract the match POS?

Comment: @Shuri1812: They represents the columns number where is a match for a specific headers array element.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Shuri1812: Welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: I just made a change in the code when I used it. As "split" was giving me an error, I replaced it with "array" and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Shuri1812: It shouldn't 'give' any error. Can you share here the way you tried? Take care, please: there must  not be any space after the comma.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was a mistake from my end. All clear now

Comment: @Shuri1812: Or, if there is a space, the split function must include it. I mean, usng it like this: `wsSrcHeaders = Split("Column 1, Column 3, Column 9", ", ")`.